# is "unlucky you" idiomatic like "lucky you"?

Tags: idioms

see [this](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define:%20%22lucky%20you%22)

> lucky devil (or lucky you, her, etc.) phrase of lucky
>   1.used to express envy at someone else's good fortune.

Ok, if a woman has just got divorce, then can I say "**unlucky you**!"

is "**unlucky you**" idiomatic like "**lucky you**"?

Comment: Not going to post as an answer because I'm not 100% sure, but what I can tell you is that I've never heard that idiomatically and am not aware of a direct equivalent for bad luck. In a situation like that I would just say "That's unlucky/unfortunate."

Comment: I think not. I wouldn't deem it idiomatic at all. It's merely a dull word play.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=cBoEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA130&dq=%22unlucky+you%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJnpTb2r3LAhVMVD4KHcSpC_AQ6AEIJTAC#v=onepage&q=%22unlucky%20you%22&f=false

Comment: @TRomano Having it in the title of a song doesn't make it idiomatic, IMO. Song titles can be pretty much *anything*.

Comment: It's not something we tend to say to people, but not because it's ungrammatical. It's fine in that regard.

Comment: *Oh, Yuck!: The Encyclopedia of Everything Nasty* https://books.google.com/books?id=3XO3FcfNWc0C&pg=PA117&dq=%22unlucky+you%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC9uHz3r3LAhUDVj4KHQ1jB-YQ6AEIaDAO#v=onepage&q=%22unlucky%20you%22&f=false

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding idiom is "Bad luck!".

The only time I can imagine somebody saying anything like "unlucky you" is if you wanted to contradict somebody who said "lucky you". For example

> A: Sylvia is visiting at the week-end
>
> B: Lucky you!
>
> A: No, **unlucky me**: she is bringing that awful guy that came with her last time!